# Unable to plot data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some data with a function following [this package tutorial](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifetimes/blob/master/docs/Quickstart.md) instructions.

This is the plot code:

```
def plot_frequency_recency_matrix(model,
                                  T=1,
                                  max_frequency=None,
                                  max_recency=None,
                                  title=None,
                                  xlabel="Customer's Historical Frequency",
                                  ylabel="Customer's Recency",
                                  **kwargs):
    """
    Plot recency frequecy matrix as heatmap.
    Plot a figure of expected transactions in T next units of time by a customer's frequency and recency.
    Parameters
    ----------
    model: lifetimes model
        A fitted lifetimes model.
    T: fload, optional
        Next units of time to make predictions for
    max_frequency: int, optional
        The maximum frequency to plot. Default is max observed frequency.
    max_recency: int, optional
        The maximum recency to plot. This also determines the age of the customer.
        Default to max observed age.
    title: str, optional
        Figure title
    xlabel: str, optional
        Figure xlabel
    ylabel: str, optional
        Figure ylabel
    kwargs
        Passed into the matplotlib.imshow command.
    Returns
    -------
    axes: matplotlib.AxesSubplot
    """
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    if max_frequency is None:
        max_frequency = int(model.data['frequency'].max())
    if max_recency is None:
        max_recency = int(model.data['T'].max())
    Z = np.zeros((max_recency + 1, max_frequency + 1))
    for i, recency in enumerate(np.arange(max_recency + 1)):
        for j, frequency in enumerate(np.arange(max_frequency + 1)):
            Z[i, j] = model.conditional_expected_number_of_purchases_up_to_time(T, frequency, recency, max_recency)
    interpolation = kwargs.pop('interpolation', 'none')
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    PCM = ax.imshow(Z, interpolation=interpolation, **kwargs)
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    if title is None:
        title = 'Expected Number of Future Purchases for {} Unit{} of Time,'. \
            format(T, "s"[T == 1:]) + '\nby Frequency and Recency of a Customer'
    plt.title(title)
    # turn matrix into square
    forceAspect(ax)
    # plot colorbar beside matrix
    plt.colorbar(PCM, ax=ax)
    return ax


def forceAspect(ax, aspect=1):
    im = ax.get_images()
    extent = im[0].get_extent()
    ax.set_aspect(abs((extent[1] - extent[0]) / (extent[3] - extent[2])) / aspect)
```

But when I run:

```
from lifetimes.plotting import plot_frequency_recency_matrix

plot_frequency_recency_matrix(bgf)
```

The sample data that I'm trying to plot:

```
    frequency  recency      T
ID
1           2    30.43  38.86
2           1     1.71  38.86
3           0     0.00  38.86
4           0     0.00  38.86
5           0     0.00  38.86
```

How can show the plot?
Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run the program? do you have an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `plt.show()` to show your plot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plot_frequency_recency_matrix(bgf)
plt.show()
```

Comment: how can I save the plot into an image file? `plt.savefig('img.png')` does not work

Comment: What "does not work" mean? Do you get an exception? Try specifying an absolute path.

Comment: I mean that it shows a blank image. I think the problem was that I called `plt.show()` before `plt.savefig('img.png')`. If I remove `plt.show()` then image is saved correctly